# Python: Replace one word in a sentence with a list of words and put thenew sentences in another column in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which SOME sentences contain the word `'o'clock'` and I want to replace the time mentioned before it with the list of hours I have and put the new sentences in another column, like in the following:

```
data= {"sentences":["I have a class at ten o'clock", "she is my friend", "she goes to school at eight o'clock"]}
my_list=['two', 'three','five','ten']
```

what I would like to see is an extra column, with the new sentences like in the following, in which the time is changed to all the times in the list:

Output :

```
     sentences                            new_sentences
0    I have a class at ten o'clock        I have a class at two o'clock, I have a class at three o'clock,...
1    she is my friend                     she is my friend
2    she goes to school at eight o'clock  she goes to school at two o'clock,....
```

repetition in the `new_sentences` column is fine. I have tried to use np.where:

```
np.where(data.str.contains('o\'clock', regex=False, case=False, na=False), data["sentence"].replace()... )
```

but I do not know how to replace the word before 'o'clock

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
# STEP 1
df1 = data['sentences'].str.extract(
    r"(?i)(?P<before>.*)\s(?P<clock>\w+(?=\so'clock))\s(?P<after>.*)")

# STEP 2
df1['clock'] = df1['clock'].str.replace(
    r'\w+', ','.join(my_list)).str.split(',')

# STEP 3
data['new_sentences'] = df1.dropna().explode('clock').agg(
    ' '.join, 1).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)

# STEP 4
data['new_sentences'] = data['new_sentences'].fillna(data['sentences'])
```

Explanation/Steps:

STEP 1: Use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) along with the given regex pattern to create a three column dataframe where the first col corresponds to the sentence before the clock `e.g. 10`, the middle column corresponds to clock itself and right column corresponds to the sentence after the clock.

```
# df1
                  before  clock    after
0      I have a class at    ten  o'clock
1                    NaN    NaN      NaN
2  she goes to school at  eight  o'clock
```

STEP 2: Use [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to replace the tokens in the clock column with all the items in `my_list`.  Then use `Series.str.split` to split the replaced tokens around the delimiter `,`.

```
# df1
                  before                    clock    after
0      I have a class at  [two, three, five, ten]  o'clock
1                    NaN                      NaN      NaN
2  she goes to school at  [two, three, five, ten]  o'clock
```

STEP 3: [`Dataframe.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) to explode the dataframe df1 around column `clock` the use the `.agg` to join the columns along axis 1. Then use groupby on level 0 to agg this datframe further.

```
# data
                             sentences                                      new_sentences
0        I have a class at ten o'clock  I have a class at two o'clock, I have a class ...
1                     she is my friend                                                NaN
2  she goes to school at eight o'clock  she goes to school at two o'clock, she goes to...
```

STEP 4: Finally use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill the missing values in the `new_sentences` column from the corresponding `sentences` column.

```
# data
                             sentences                                      new_sentences
0        I have a class at ten o'clock  I have a class at two o'clock, I have a class ...
1                     she is my friend                                   she is my friend
2  she goes to school at eight o'clock  she goes to school at two o'clock, she goes to...
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer and detailed explanation, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in line with what you were expecting?

```py
import re
data= {"sentences":["I have a class at ten o'clock", "she is my friend", "she goes to school at eight o'clock"]}
my_list=['two', 'three','five','ten']

regex = re.compile(r"(\w+) (?=o'clock)", re.IGNORECASE)
new = []

for i in data["sentences"]:
    for j in my_list:
        new.append(re.sub(regex, j + ' ', i))

new = list(set(new))

print(new)
```

Output:

```
I have a class at two o'clock
I have a class at ten o'clock
she goes to school at two o'clock
she goes to school at five o'clock
I have a class at five o'clock
I have a class at three o'clock
she goes to school at ten o'clock
she goes to school at three o'clock
she is my friend
```

OR equivalent:

```py
import re
data= {"sentences":["I have a class at ten o'clock", "she is my friend", "she goes to school at eight o'clock"]}
my_list=['two', 'three','five','ten']
regex = re.compile(r"(\w+) (?=o'clock)", re.IGNORECASE)
x = list(set([re.sub(regex, j + ' ', i) for j in my_list for i in data["sentences"]]))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. however, what I would like to see is a new column in the dataframe including the new sentences as a list or string like the one in the question. do you know if there is a way of doing that in a column in the df?

Comment: Apologies - I missed the part where you said it was a dataframe - I'll give it a go

Comment: thank you very much. yes the dataframe is the important part as I like to see the sentences similar to the output above.