# Python: Replace multiple words in a column with multiple words from a list and write them to a different column in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, list

I have a dataframe and a list as follows:

```
data = {{"text":["I have one apple and two bananas", "this is my apple", "she has three apples","My friend has five apples but she only has one banana"]}
df= pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['text'])

my_list = ['one','two','three','four','five']
```

what I would like to have as an output is an extra column 'new_text' where the sentences containing the words from the list are replaced with each and every word from my_list, so the output would look like this:

```
output:
```

```
  text                               new_text
0 I have one apple and two bananas   I have two apple and three bananas, I have three apple and four bananas,I have four apple and five bananas,I have five apple and one bananas,...
1 this is my apple                   this is my apple
2 she has three apples               she has two apples,she has four apples,she has five apples,...

and so on...
```

the repetition of the same sentence and plural cases does not matter, the only important thing is that all the words from the list appear in the sentences in the 'new_text' column

I have tried the code here: [Python: Replace one word in a sentence with a list of words and put thenew sentences in another column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62465200/python-replace-one-word-in-a-sentence-with-a-list-of-words-and-put-thenew-sente)

with an exception in step 1, but it only finds the first word :

```
 data1 = data['text'].str.extract(
r"(?i)(?P<before>.*)\s(?P<clock>\(?=\bone\b | \btwo\b | \bthree\b | \bfour\b | \bfive\b))\s(?P<after>.*)")
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
a = ["I have one apple and two bananas", "this is my apple",
     "she has three apples", "My friend has five apples but she only has one banana"]

b = ['one','two','three','four','five', 'six']

new = []
for sentence in a:
    newSen = []

    for word in sentence.split():
        if word in b:
             newSen.append(b[b.index(word) + 1])
        else:
            newSen.append(word)

    new.append(' '.join(newSen))

print(new) #output : ['I have two apple and three bananas', 'this is my apple', 'she has four apples', 'My friend has six apples but she only has two banana']
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however, what I have here is a list and a dataframe, and I would like to have the new sentences in a column in the dataframe rather than a list, similar to the above mentioned output.

Comment: You just have to add this list to the data frame :)

Comment: I also see that the output from print(new) only uses the words from the list 'b' once, but what I would like to see is that all the possible combinations of numbers to happen in the sentences

Comment: All numbers from 0 to ?

Comment: not from zero, but all the numbers that appear in list b, so for example for the first sentence it would change to :  I have two apple and three bananas, I have three apple and four bananas,I have four apple and five bananas,I have five apple and one bananas,...